# Rational Zeros Theorem Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

All proofs of this theorem involve first multiplying by q^n and then factoring p.

E.g., from wiki (srry, too lazy to figure out how to use mathjax right now)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Why can I not just factor p out immediately and put a₀ on the other side of the equation? Isn't that enough to show that p must be a factor of a₀?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you multiply out by $q^n$, your equation is not an equation of integers, but of rational numbers. At that point, any argument concerning divisibility and coprime numbers is completely false. You have to remove every fraction in the equality before you can make any sort of divisibility argument.

Comment: Ufff, I'm dense at times. I don't understand how something so obvious confused me...